# ExtJS 4 Problems with hiding the root node in a tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a tree panel which loads data after a keystroke in a text field. If I set the root node to be hidden, when the tree loads it steals focus from the text field. If I dont hide the root note it works perfect...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you manually set the focus back to the text field at the end of your keystroke function?

Comment: I can, but there is about a one second gap between loosing and regaining focus, which is far too long when you are typing. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: can you post the definitions for your tree panel and text field, I'd like to step through the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per i know you need to write the code to display tree panel in **change** event of text field.Then if you change the key in textfield it will never loose the focus and you will get the result by each key change.